# Inject attribute doesn't work for field

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, ninject-2

Inject attribute is not working for field.

```
[Inject]
public MyContext context; //Not injected

[Inject]
public MyContext context {get; set;} //Injected
```

I am using default Ninject settings. Why field is not injected ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is not allowed.

From the Ninject 2 Beta [announcement](http://kohari.org/2009/02/25/ninject-2-reaches-beta/):

> Things that were in Ninject 1.x that
>   are not in Ninject 2:
>
> - Field injection: Ninject 2’s
>     injection is now driven by expression
>     trees, and in .NET 3.5 there is no way
>     to set field values with an expression
>     tree. Since this is a bad practice
>     anyway, I decided to cut it.

Comment: Since the author of Ninject removed support for injection of fields, he should have removed the `AttributeTargets.Field` decoration on the `InjectAttribute`. In other words, there is a bug in Ninject, because the code given in the question should not compile.

Comment: @Steven - You are right. I spent my time unnecessarily just because of this.