# How to make the InjectAttribute work with an IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have this ViewModel

```
public class CustomerSuscribeViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IDataUsers DataUsers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if(DataUsers.Get(new UserFilter() {Email = Email}).Any())
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(This Email is already used.",new string[]{"Email"});
        }
        if(ConfirmPassword != Password)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please confirm your apssword", new string[] { "Password", "ConfirmPassword" });
    }
}
```

and this action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Suscribe(CustomerSuscribeViewModel customer)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(customer);
```

The problem is the member DataUsers is never created, so I get a NullReferenceException.

The binding is done by :

```
Bind<IDataUsers>().To<DataUsers>();
```

Any Idea ?

EDIT : The InjectAttribute works well for properties inside my controllers.

Environnement : asp.net mvc 3 , ninject 2.2 (maybe I need to update ?)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532812/inject-attribute-doesnt-work-for-field

Comment: DataUsers is a property not a field

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Just reading about the InjectAttribute, are you creating the CustomerSuscribeViewModel objects with ninject?

Comment: As you can see in my action's signature, the CustomerSuscribeViewModel is instantiate by .net via it's binding from the http request I guess.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488529/how-to-override-the-asp-net-mvc-3-default-model-binder-to-resolve-dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View Models are not created by Ninject so the inject attribute is ignored. Usually view models should be kept simple and have no dependencies. You can get there by using `ValidationAttribute`s instead of `IValidatableObject`

Read https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Injection-of-validators about injection of validation attributes.

- Example: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/SampleApplication/Models/Movie/PriceRangeAttribute.cs

Here is an example of how one can achieve the validation of the password vs confirmation password matching using a `ValidationAttribute`:

- Implementation: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/SampleApplication/Models/Account/CompareAttribute.cs
- Usage: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/SampleApplication/Models/Account/RegisterModel.cs

Comment: Great, perfect ! Darin solution in the other link said that my practice is an anti pattern but he didn't gave an other solution. yours seems like perfect !